# bootstrap btn-group stay inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/rt3kx/9/

Each button group in the table is split into two lines.

Although I am aware that Bootstrap is not designed to be a just-add-water framework, and
defining my own style would solve the problem, in this context, I would like to see if there is a solution without customisation.

This is a workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/rt3kx/10/

Essentially what it does is to give the table cell more space by using

```
<td class="span2">
```

However, this is not an elegant solution as the cell occupies more than necessary space.

Can anyone suggest a better solution, please?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own style with a fixed width and apply it to that btn-group div.  Bootstrap is meant to be extended by the people who use it so not everything has to be done using bootstrap classes.

Make a separate CSS file, add a class with a fixed width and then apply it to your div.

Comment: I can see that working, and agree with your idea of bootstrap being just a base for extension.

I meant to explore Bootstrap though. Should have mentioned not to use customised style.